# Can you update a column with a select statement in one query

Tags: sql-server

For example right now I have three queries. An insert and select statement for one table:

```
INSERT INTO Table_A (col_1)
VALUES (val_1)
```

and

```
SELECT SUM(col_1)
FROM Table_A
WHERE Table_A_ID = id
```

After each insert I need to recalculate the sum and update the column of Table_B.

That sum is stored in a variable, 'sum', (I'm using dapper), and then passed to another function along with an 'id' variable which updates a column of Table_B.

```
UPDATE Table_B
SET col_1 = @sum
WHERE Table_B_ID = @id
```

I'd like to combine the last two queries to effectively achieve something like:

```
UPDATE Table_B
SET col_1 = (SELECT Sum(col_1) FROM Table_A WHERE Table_A_ID = id)
WHERE Table_B_ID = id
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
UPDATE @Table_B 
SET col_1 = a.col_1
FROM (SELECT SUM(col_1) AS col_1 FROM @Table_A WHERE a.[id] = @id) a
WHERE [id] = @id
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it really necessary to store a calculated column ?

If it is, you could consider creating a trigger on Table A that is executed each time a record is inserted in 'A'.  The trigger could then update table_B with the calculated sum.

(Keep in mind that you'll have to modify the calculated sum in Table-B when a record in Table-A is deleted or updated as well.  The trigger should thus be an AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE  trigger.)